# Pseudorandom Sequence Generator not just a number generator

Tags: integer, random, sequence, prng

I need an algorithm that pretty much will turn a unix timestamp into a suitably random number, so that if I "play back" the timestamps I get the same random numbers.

And here's what I mean by suitably:

1. Most humans will not detect a loop or pattern in the random numbers.
2. It need not be cryptographically secure.
3. All numbers must be capable of being generated. (I've found that LFSR don't do this)
4. The numbers are 32 bit integers

And I would like it to be fairly fast.

So far my idea is to just seed a PRNG over and over, but I'm not sure if that's the best way to handle this.

Any thoughts and ideas will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If you change the sequence of timestamps, do you want to get the same random numbers in a different order? E.g. starting w/ [(1, 5), (2, 3), (3,9)], where the first number in a pair is the timestamp, would you want [(2,3), (3,9), (1,5)] or [(2,7), (3,4), (1,6)]?

Comment: XKCD to the rescue! - http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: Good point outis, this would distinguish a hash from a prng.

Comment: @outis, the timestamps will never be played out of order, but I'm going to investigate hashing anyways as it seems like a quick solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it doesn't need to be statistically random, perhaps feed the timestamps to MD5 and truncate the hash. The main issue is that I don't know if this would be surjective. Other hashing algorithms might work better.

Comment: If the random numbers are for human consumption, it's unlikely that a hash collision would be quickly distinguished. MD4, MD5 would be pretty fast.

Comment: I'm going to test the hashing and see how the distribution looks.  I'm wanting something that has a distribution that is close to being random, but it doesn't have to be that close, if you catch my drift.

Comment: I went ahead and marked this as the accepted answer because it was what I used, though the other solutions here may prove to be equally as useful.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that the easiest thing to do is feed your time to [jrand48](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/jrand48.html).  Something like

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int mix(int t) {
    unsigned short x[3] = {t, t<<16, t};
    return jrand48(x);
}
```

It's reversible (2<sup>16</sup>·x+n≡0x5deece66d·(2<sup>32</sup>+1)·t+0xb mod 2<sup>48</sup> ⇒ t≡0xdfe05bcb1365·(2<sup>16</sup>·x+n-0xb) mod 2<sup>48</sup> where n∈[0,2<sup>16</sup>)) but since it's the high 32 bits out of 48-bit, it's actually not too easy.  (You can apply `jrand48` to `x` more than once too; as long as you don't apply it 2<sup>48</sup>-1 times, the same sorts of properties will hold.)

Comment: I'm not understanding reversibility to know whether I need it or not.  Is that essentially taking the generated number and getting the seed (timestamp) back?

Comment: Yes.  Treating `x` as a 48-bit number, we set `x=(2^32+1)*t`, then `jrand48` changes it to `0x5deece66d*x+0xb` and returns the high 32 bits.  It just takes a little bit of modular arithmetic to work out the inverse, i.e. go from the output of `jrand48` back to the original `t`.  This isn't generally in general (32-bit output isn't enough to nail down 48-bit state) but since we only have 32-bit input, it is here.

Comment: Do you mean 't>>16' rather than 't<<16'?  What you have shifts the low-order 16 bits of t to the high order 16 bits, and the conversion to short then discards the high order 16 bits, so you have written '{ t, 0, t }' a funny way.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at the POSIX-compliant [`drand48()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/drand48.html) family of functions.  They give decent (but certainly not cryptographic) random numbers, and `srand48()` takes a 32-bit seed value.  They are deterministic, so reusing a given seed will regenerate the same sequence of numbers again.

Comment: I didn't see your answer earlier; mine is pretty much the same, but using `(erand48/nrand48/jrand48)` is more direct than `srand48+(drand48/lrand48/mrand48)`.

Comment: @ephemient: It's all in the family :-)

Answer (score 0):

`(timestamp ^ 0x12345678) + 12345678` Is this subtle enough?

If you don't care about reversibility of it you could crc32 each timestamp.